# How to use private properties in a method who'll be an event listener

Tags: javascript

I have a class with private properties which will be read in a method, that method will be called in an `addEventListener()` as a callback function. But JavaScript doesn't allow it for some reason, it throws an error:

> Cannot read private member #start from an object whose class did not
> declare it

Using getters doesn't work either since JavaScript appears to create new undefined properties when attempting to call the getter.

Here's the code:

```js
class Load {
  #start;
  #end;
  constructor(){
    this.#start = 0;
    this.#end = 5;
  }
  get start(){return this.#start}
  get end(){return this.#end}
  
  next(evt){
    const event = evt.target;
    event.innerText = `start: ${this.#start}. end: ${this.#end}`;
  }
}

const load = new Load();
document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('click', load.next);
```

```css
div{
  width: 200px;
  padding: 50px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>click me</div>
```

is there a workaround for it to work or am I doing something wrong?

Someone please help

Comment: `load.next.bind(load)` instead of `load.next`.

Comment: Either make the `next` method arrow function or bind the method as `load.next.bind(load)`